# How can I initialize a list and append objects of any type to it in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python program that will initialize a list and add objects of any type to the list. I believe that I have initialized the list properly in my `__init__` method, but I cannot seem to pass any objects to it using the `.join()` method. I chose the `.join()` method because the `.append()` doesn't seem to handle object type `str`.

```
class Bag(object):
    '''This is where the docstring goes.'''

    def __init__(self):
        self.contents = []

    def put_in_bag(self, contents):
        contents.join(contents)

    def __str__(self):
        return "The bag has: " + str(self.contents)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bag1 = Bag()
    bag1.put_in_bag("comb")
    bag1.put_in_bag("candy bar")
    print bag1
```

I receive the following output:

`The bag has: []`

This is homework for a college course and I am an inexperienced Python programmer. It seems like it should be pretty straight forward, but I am obviously missing something.

Comment: python lists can hold any type by default; `append` is in fact what you want. The big thing you're missing is in your `put_in_bag` method, you are referencing `contents` in the body rather than `self.contents`. Something like `self.contents.append(contents)` should work for ya

Comment: `append`, not `join`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not referencing the `contents` on the object instance (`self`) in the `put_in_bag` method; instead you're trying to join the argument to the argument itself and not touching the instance at all. Also, `join` is not a Python method on `list`s. Since you're adding single elements, you want `append`. If you want to add an entire list, use `+=`.

Try this:

```
class Bag(object):
    '''This is where the docstring goes.'''

    def __init__(self):
        self.contents = []

    def put_in_bag(self, contents):
        self.contents.append(contents)

    def __str__(self):
        return "The bag has: " + str(self.contents)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bag1 = Bag()
    bag1.put_in_bag("comb")
    bag1.put_in_bag("candy bar")
    print(bag1)
```